# Nested Elements in MongoDB from CSV import

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, nested

I have the following CSV file:

```
Website Company name    City    State   Zip Country Founded year    Company email   Twitter Followers   Employees   Revenue Public/Private/Nonprofit    Industry    Monthly Technology Spend    First name  Last name   Title   Email   Confidence  Phone
website.com Some Company    Sydney  NSW 2010    Australia   2012    support@company.com 94750   100 - 250   $1 - 10M    Private Design  $5K - 20K   Fred    Smith   Mixing Technology and Accounting            
website.com Some Company    Sydney  NSW 2010    Australia   2012    support@company.com 94750   100 - 250   $1 - 10M    Private Design  $5K - 20K   Joe Bloggs  Secret Projects         
website.com Some Company    Sydney  NSW 2010    Australia   2012    support@company.com 94750   100 - 250   $1 - 10M    Private Design  $5K - 20K   Adam    Davids  Head of Growth  Adam@company.com    Grey    
website.com Some Company    Sydney  NSW 2010    Australia   2012    support@company.com 94750   100 - 250   $1 - 10M    Private Design  $5K - 20K   Angela  Johns   Senior Marketing Manager    angela@company.com  Grey
```

The data seems to be not properly aligned but I'm sure you get the point.

The question is how would you set the data out in the csv so that you could get the mongoDB record has a URL

and then an array of company data and employee data.

i.e

```
   "URL" : Website.com
   "CompanyInfo" : [
    {
            "Company Name" : "",
            "City" : "",
            "State" : "",
            "Zip" : "",
             "Country" : "",
            "Founded year" : "",
            "company email" : "",
            "Twitter Followers" : "",
            "Employees" : "",
            "Revenue" : "",
            "Public/Private" : "",
            "Industry" : ""
            "Monthly Tech Spend" : ""
    }, etc...

"employees" : [
    {
            "First name" : "fred",
            "Last Name" : "Smith",
            "Title" : "Mixing Technology and Accounting",
            "Email" : "",
    }, etc... ]
```

The record example may not be perfect but hopefully it gives you an idea of what I want to achieve

Comment: Embedded formats are not supported by `mongoimport`. You can use `mongoexport` on embedded structures, but all it will do it make the embedded detail a "string". Therefore by the same token all you could do is use the same type of "string" format, and then do another pass through the data to update and turn that into embedded detail. If you want to import in as "embedded", then you use JSON format instead. That's what it's there for.

Comment: If you want to write your own "flat file import" yourself, then good luck with that. Of course all of the rules and the logic need to be written by you. But for my money, if you have a "CSV export" then it actually came from somewhere. So I think the time would be better invested making that "somewhere" export in a JSON format you could import directly instead.